# R PMML probabilities precision

Tags: r, random-forest, pmml

Using PMML model file to score a random forest. When scoring getting the following output. Is there a way to increase the number of decimal points for probability? (ie.  0.8 to 0.8000 or 0.2 to 0.2000)

```
library(randomForest)
library(pmml)

iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, ntree=5)
saveXML(pmml(iris.rf), file="irisrf.xml")
```

this model is saved as PMML file and evaluated to get the following output
{
  "Species" : "setosa",
  "Predicted_Species" : "setosa",
  "Probability_setosa" : 0.8,
  "Probability_versicolor" : 0.2,
  "Probability_virginica" : 0.0
}

Comment: I don't see the code, but then again, I'm not in the Matrix.

Comment: iris.rf  <- randomForest(species ~ ., data=iris, ntree=5) is the code used

Comment: Please incorporate this into your question.

Comment: Also add code you use to write the result and please format the code chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RF model contains five decision trees. Class probabilities are calculated by dividing the number of decision trees that voted for a particular class by the total number of decision trees.

In your example, one decision tree voted for class "versicolor" (`1 / 5 = 0.2`), and the remaining four decision trees voted for class "setosa" (`4 / 5 = 0.8`).

You cannot change the "precision" of the division operator `/`. Instead, simply pretty-print fractions `1 / 5` and `4 / 5` with as many decimal places as needed in your application code:

```
System.out.printf("%.4f", probability);
```